# Why URI parameters are unknown for apache camel debezuim mongodb connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, debezium, change-data-capture

I am getting this error when configuring a camel route for mondodb debezium.

```
org.apache.camel.reifier.AbstractReifier.resolveEndpoint(AbstractReifier.java:195)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:96)
at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.createRoute(RouteReifier.java:76)
... 29 more\r\nCaused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: 
debezium-mongodb://MY-EVENT-LISTENER?mongodbHosts=abc-de-u1234.net%3A27017
&mongodbName=myMongoDb
&mongodbPassword=xxxxxx
&mongodbUser=xxxxxx
&offsetStorageFileName=c%3A%5Ctemp%5Coffset-file-1.dat
&topicPrefix=dbz1 due to: 
There are 2 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. 
Unknown parameters=[{mongodbHosts=abc-de-u1234.net:27017, mongodbName=myMongoDb}]
```

My gradle dependency is

```
dependencies {
   
    

    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-debezium-mongodb-starter:4.0.0'
...
}
```

Looking forward for some expert's help to get the issue resolved.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The options available is listed in the docs at:
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/debezium-mongodb-component.html

Comment: Thank you Claus
I am using connectionstring with replicaSet and readPreference paramters and mongodb-debezium connector takes only first parameter and compains that second parameter is unknown property

abc-de-u1234.net:27017/?replicaSet=MGORPST_3275&readPreference=nearest